# Javascript: printing all possible permutations to get sum

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a piece of code to run but got stuck.
I have an array of sizes `var sizes = [1,2];` and I have a length I want to reach `len = 3;`. I want to print all the possibilities to reach this length using my given sizes, that is: [1,1,1], [2,1], [1,2].

I tried this so far:

```
var sizes = [1,2];  // possible sizes to pick
var start_len = 3;  // length I want to reach
var arr = [];

var main = function(len){
    if(len == 0){arr = [];}  //clear the array after I got to full length
    if(len >= 1){            // try adding 1
        B(1,len, arr);
    }
    if(len >= 2){            // try adding 2
        B(2,len, arr);
    }
}
var add_and_call_again= function(elem, len, arr){
    arr.push(elem);
    if(len-elem == 0){    // if got to full length
        console.log(arr);
    }
    main(len-elem);       // add next element with less length to fill
}    
main(start_len);
```

What I got was [1,1,1] and [2,1], but also a [2] - not sure what went wrong. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My question shows my code but what I want to understand is the pseudo code for that. I'm missing something and I don't know what

Comment: Too cryptic. Use meaningful names in your code and explain it. Also, use a debugger (stack overflow **is not a debugger**)

Comment: Search knapsack problem on google, this seems similar

Comment: What is this `B` function doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive depth-first search is the best option for such tasks. Universal code (any sizes, any goal):

```
var sizes = [1, 2];  // possible sizes to pick
var start_len = 3;

function dfs(current_len, path){
    var res = [];
    sizes.forEach(function(s){
        var temp_res;
        if (s==current_len)
            res.push(path.concat([s]));
        else if (s<current_len)
            temp_res = dfs(current_len-s, path.concat([s]));
        if (temp_res)
            res = res.concat(temp_res);
    });
    if (res.length)
        return res;
 }

 var paths = dfs(start_len, []);
 console.log(paths);
```

Comment: your code gives "[Array[3], Array[2], Array[2]]"  but I need the elements themselves {1,1,1}, {1,2}, {2,1} and {3}

Comment: console.log(paths); gives [ [ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 1 ] ]. If you see Array[3] - it just means console.log doesn't show embedded arrays in your case